# Dual Monitors on Integrated VGA and Video Card VGA

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I'm not sure if this site is the best place for this question, if there is another stack exchange site where this would be more appropriate, please suggest it, or move it there.

I have a VGA port on my desktop computer that is integrated, and I also installed a video card that has a VGA, HDMI and DVI port. I connected my main monitor to the video card, and all is well. However, I have a second monitor that I connected to the VGA port of my integrated video card (the one that's on the motherboard). When I go to the Display properties of my PC, I can't see the 2nd monitor.

Is it possible to use a setup like this? Or do I need to get a VGA to DVI converter and use the video card? If it IS possible could it support 3 monitors (one vga, one vga -integrated and one dvi?)?

Comment: If you're using two monitors, you really want them both connected to the video card. However, using multiple monitors on multiple video cards is fully supported in Windows 7. You'll need to make sure your BIOS enables the onboard video and that drivers for it are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a setup like this?

Depends on the BIOS. It might disable the on-board when a discrete card is plugged in, but this also may be configurable in the BIOS menu.

> If it IS possible could it support 3 monitors (one vga, one vga -integrated and one dvi?)?

See the previous statement, plus the video card would have to support 2 displays itself to begin with.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, apparently the monitor I had was broken, and the ports were working fine all along.